# flatten / group generated files in android studio flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

Coming from PHPStorm the IDE by default folds / collapses similar files to one level.

So for example when I have a `file.ts` and `file.js` in the same folder, `file.js` will be hidden in a dropdown below `file.ts` because PHPStorm knows its generated and assumes the files are related.

Is there a similiar feature in Android Studio when using Flutter?

I want to group / collapse my `.freezed.dart` and `.g.dart` files so they are hidden from the project view but not ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[File nesting rules | IntelliJ IDEA Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-nesting-dialog.html)

This works for all IntelliJ-based IDEs.

1. In the Project tool window (`Alt+1`), open options.

new UI: [image: new UI]

old UI: [image: old UI]

2. Select File Nesting. A dialog opens in which you can configure file nesting rules.
3. Add new rules:

```
.freezed.dart; .g.dart;
```

[image: rules]